# Does ssh-keygen have a command to change the setting on a public key?

Tags: restrictions, authorized-keys, ssh-keygen

Does ssh-keygen have an option for setting the values like `force-command`, `no-port-forwarding`, `no-agent-forwarding` on a supplied key?

I am thinking of the instance, when someone sends you their public key and you want to restrict the commands the key will allow.

I know those options can be changed in an editor, but I prefer the option where it can be set from the command line.

I have seen some ssh-keygen certificate options in the documentation, but I am not sure whether they apply to a public key supplied by another person.

Comment: Keys as such don't have options. If you put a user's key in your `authorized_keys` file, _that entry_ (line) can have such options _in addition to_ the key; see [man 8 sshd](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd.8#AUTHORIZED_KEYS_FILE_FORMAT). OpenSSH certificates _contain_ similar options, because with certs you normally put only the one CA key in authorized_keys, marked as cert-authority, not the individual keys. Of course this requires the user submit their publickey, you create the cert and give it back, and the user uses the cert and _not_ their bare key.

Comment: @dave_thompson Spot on. Your comment should be an answer.